# Iterate points for OpenCV's Line function

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to iterate from two tuples to create a line connection previous points to currents points.

```
    for (x,y) in currFeatures and (px,py) in self.prev_draw_features:
            cv.line(new_image, (px,py),(x,y),cv.RGB(125, 20,200),5)
```

Which then leads me to this error:

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1309631642.294530]
> bad callback: <bound method
> cached_subscriber.callback of
> <**main**.cached_subscriber instance
> at 0x2bbb290>> Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py",
> line 563, in _invoke_callback
> cb(msg)   File "****",
> line 70, in callback
> for (x,y) in currFeatures and (px,py) in self.prev_draw_features:
> NameError: global name 'px' is not
> defined

Is it possible to iterate between two tuples at the exact same time, or will I need to construct a new variable to iterate between the elements.  Keep in mind that the tuples may not be equal (which probably negates my "and" statement.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10465/iterate-points-for-opencv%27s-line-function/) by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2011-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you probably want is:

```
for ((x,y), (px,py)) in zip(currFeatures, self.prev_draw_features):
        cv.line(new_image, (px,py),(x,y),cv.RGB(125, 20,200),5)
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on 2011-07-06**:
Yeah I will.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-05**:
Could you post how you fixed it for the benefit of future users?

**Comment by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on 2011-07-05**:
Okay I got it fixed thanks!

**Comment by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on 2011-07-05**:
I get new image from a live feed camera.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-03**:
How do you get "new_image"? I think that is the only parameter that has to be a numpy array.

**Comment by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on 2011-07-02**:
Okay I did try that but then I got the error:  File "****", line 73, in callback
cv.line(new_image, (px,py),(x,y),cv.RGB(125, 20,200),5)
TypeError:  is not a numpy array   Would I need to first extract all of the information out then re-insert it in?